# Dart JavaScript interop callbacks with jQuery

Tags: javascript, dart

How can I translate the following jquery code to Dart? I'm having difficulty getting the alert callback to work using js.interop.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('p').hide('slow', function() {
      alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

thanks for your question! I wasn't sure myself, but turns out this is possible. :)

First off, add `js` to your pubspec.yaml:

```
name:  jquerydart
description:  A sample application

dependencies:
  js: any
```

Then, run *pub install*, either via the command line or via Dart Editor.

Then, in your Dart file:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

hideIsDone() {
  window.alert('all done!');
}

void main() {
  js.scoped(() {
    js.context.jQuery('p').hide(1000, new js.Callback.once(() => hideIsDone()));
  });
}
```

Note that to callback from JS into Dart, you need to create a Callback object.

Also note you cannot use `$` for the jQuery variable, as dart2js also uses `$`. So in the meantime you need to use `jQuery` in your Dart code.

Having said all that, it's cool that we can use jQuery via JS-Dart interop, but Dart should really do this for us. So I opened bug http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6526

Comment: Personally I'm not thrilled seeing people trying to use jQuery in Dart (or even in JS for that matter). I rather want to see a good base support for things like manipulating the DOM (which is quite good in Dart already), and then combined with nice libraries for animation etc. The issue you created helps in this regard.

Comment: I agree Kai, but it's a good bridge service to have during these early days.

Comment: I agree @KaiSellgren please star the bug and open more :)

Comment: Can you replace "() => hideIsDone()" with "hideIsDone"?

Comment: @Shannon-jjBehrens I think I tried that, but there was some bug in Dartium. Might be fixed now.

Comment: @SethLadd. Is this solution still valid? I cannot find scoped() and Callback.once in `js` package.

Comment: There is still a js package, but I don't know if this specific solution still works. Might be better to use the newer `dart:js` library.

Comment: Kai, there isn't always an option when, for instance, using a third party lib that extends jQuery. @SethLadd, perhaps it's time to update https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/ to include usage of 'package:js/js.dart'.

Answer (score 6):

First add the `js` dependency to your *pubspec.yaml* :

```yaml
dependencies:
  js: any
```

By using *js-interop* you can write almost the same code as in *javascript*.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  js.scoped(() {
    js.context.$(new js.Callback.once(($) {
      $('p').hide('slow', new js.Callback.once(() {
        js.context.alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
      }));
    }));
  });
}
```

The main differences are :

- You have to use `js.Callback.once` or `js.Callback.many` to set your callback functions. Use `js.Callback.once` if your callback is call only one time.
- Your code must be wrapped with the `js.scoped`. Basically, [managing proxy lifetimes](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/#managing-proxy-lifetimes) is here to prevent memory leak.

That said, you can simplify the above code :

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  js.scoped(() {
    js.context.$('p').hide('slow', new js.Callback.once(() {
      window.alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    }));
  });
}
```

The changes are :

- `js.context.$(new js.Callback.once(($) {` isn't needed because `main` is equivalent to the jQuery `$(function)`.
- `js.context.alert` has been replace by `window.alert` : it's more efficient to directly use *DART* functions instead of communicate with *JS*.