# How to call a jQuery function from Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

This is a typical situation in jQuery:

```js
$(".myClass").myFunction({
    aKey: 'some value'
});
```

How do you call that using dart:js?

The [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js.html) is a bit cryptic and a similar question that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223840/dart-javascript-interop-callbacks-with-jquery) seems dated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do :

```dart
main() {
  js.context.callMethod(r'$', ['.myClass'])
      .callMethod('myFunction', [new js.JsObject.jsify({'aKey': 'some value'})]);
}
```

Comment: Yikes. I don't suppose there's any reason to actually do this, right? Or will I be having to maintain code like this in another few years... (I mean, there's probably no advantage to using dart in a situation like this, so we probably won't see much of this kind of thing, right?)

Comment: Actually _package:js_ provides a simpler API and you can keep on using it. See the similar question you mention. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590148/how-do-you-interact-with-js-from-dart/20594873#20594873 for _dart:js_ vs. _package:js_.

Comment: Truly acrobatic! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the build-in funcitons querySelector or querySelectorAll instead of the jQuery selector. So it would be:

```
main(){   
    querySelector(".myClass").myFunction(){
        aKey: 'some value'
    } 
}
```

or for mulitple elements:

```
main(){
    querySelectorAll(".myClass").myFunction(){
        aKey: 'some value'
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use [DQuery](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html) instead.

> DQuery is a porting of jQuery in Dart.