# How to call function in bootstrap.js from dart code

Tags: dart

I have an AnchroElement generated after page is loaded.

```
<a id="yvs" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Your voyage schedule">YVS</a>
```

How can i call the $('#yvs').tooltip(options) in my dart script using 'dart:js'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call a jQuery function from dart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755337/how-to-call-a-jquery-function-from-dart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

main() {
  js.context.callMethod('$',['#yvs'])
      .callMethod('tooltip', [new js.JsObject.jsify(options)]);
}
```